# Simple Camera Mapping in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

Im trying to do some simple camera mapping using an equirectangular env.map that I have created from my real camera.
This I am trying to project onto my scene geometry.
This used to be done with sticky coordinates and there is also the UV Projection modifier.
Unfortunately I need it to work with cycles.
I am trying to use UV mapping, but am not sure whether to use a normal image texture or an env texture in my material nodes. The question is also what kind of texture coordinates I should use.

Thx in advance, R